# Sharepoint Lists Move From One Site Collection to Other

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint and we have dev and prod environments which are essentially different site collections on the same server. We have to move certain lists with contents from dev site collection to prod site collection and wondering what's the best way to do it? I know i can do it with Export a list through Central Administration and then restore it through Powershell but is that the only way? we will have to do it often and that's why wondering if someone can advise us what's the best practise and how to implement that practise (hints) etc will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the List Setting page on dev "Save list as template" with "Include content". mention name.
2.Go to site setting page Click on "List templates" Under "gallaries" section. and download the .stp file from List template gallary of dev.
3.Upload the list template on PROD in list tempalate gallary(Site setting-> List templates).
4.Create List.while creating list you will find the earlier created template.Select this template and create list.

Thanks.